# lexical analyzer. count the total number of unrecognized lexemes

Tags: lex

how can i calculate the total number of lexemes that have not been converted into tokens?
I want to find the total number of lexical errors ie unrecognised lexemes.
considering i have deleted all the blank spaces, new line, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to count the number of times you find a sequence of characters that are not recognized as a token, you can add this rule to the very end of the rules in your .l file, after the rules that discard whitespace, etc.

```
.+ {badSequences++; }
```